# How can I skip the first and last line while using grep?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I am using grep to find any files that contain the word "hello" in the current directory:

```
grep -l 'hello' *
```

Given these files:

*test1*

```
hello
hi
how are you
stuff
```

*test2*

```
welcome
hello
etc
```

*test3*

```
hey
there
hello
```

The output is:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

However, I want to search these files for the word "hello", but skip the first and last lines, so my output is:

```
test2
```

I know I can use the following command to ignore the first and last lines:

```
sed '1d;$d' *
```

But is there any way to use this with grep, so that it ignores the first and last line of each file? If not, how exactly can I use grep to skip the first and last line of each file?

Comment: you want to skip the first/last lines of each input file? or you want to skip the first/last lines of the resulting output set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
for file in *; do sed '1d;$d' "$file" | grep -q hello && echo "$file"; done
```

Answer (score 4):

This task is more suited to `awk`.

```bash
awk 'FNR == 1 {p=""; next}
     p ~ /hello/ {print FILENAME; nextfile}
     {p = $0}' test*

test2
```

There is no need to loop and call external utilities `sed`, `grep` multiple times for each iteration.

Comment: How can this work on line 2 if `p` is not already defined @anubhava ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot: It works for line 2 because we evaluate condition `p ~ /hello/` when we are on line #3.

Comment: Don't get it, `p ~ /hello/` is on `$0` by default on line #3 AFAIK

Comment: No, not on `$0`. Comparison is against the variable `p` which was set equal to `$0` when we processed previous line i.e. line #2.

Comment: Sneaky ! Nice answer ^^

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -sn '1d;$d;/hello/{F;:a;n;ba}' test*
```

Turn off implicit printing and treat each file separately.

Delete the first and last lines.

Output file name and quit if a match for `hello` is found.

Alternative:

```
parallel -k 'tail -n+2 {} | head -n-1 | grep -qm1 hello && echo {}' ::: test*
```

or:

```
parallel -kq sed -n '1d;$d;/hello/{F;q}' {} ::: test*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using the following code:

```
grep 'hello' test* | tail -n +2 | head -n -1
```

Comment: That solves a totally different problem - it removes the first and last found lines across all files instead of not looking for `hello` in the first and last line of each file.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton, you are completely right

Answer (score -1):

assuming the files are less than `500 MB` or so each, just do it all in 1 shot :

```
 for __ in testfile_7000*txt; do

     echo "\n $__\n\n$( gcat -b "$__" |
                        gcat -n       )\n"
 done

 echo " searching for \"hello\" .....\n\n$(

    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "testfile_7000*txt" -print0 |

    xargs -0 mawk 'BEGIN { OFS = FS = RS; RS = "^$"
                         _ = "" 
             } $!NF = $+($!_=$(NF-(_==$NF))=_)~"hello" ? FILENAME :_' | gcat -n )\n"
```

---

```
 testfile_7000001.txt

     1       1  000hello
     2  
     3       2  testhello
     4       3   4355345


 testfile_7000002.txt

     1       1  000hell0
     2       2  testhllo
     3       3  84355345hello

 searching for "hello" .....

     1  ./testfile_7000001.txt
```

- 2nd line of 1st file is an empty line `""`